# Javascript: How to parse a line out of a multi-line string?

Tags: javascript

Currently I have a big string paragraph displayed using `<pre>` like the following where each line is represented using new line:

```
SchoolDistrictCode:291238-9
location_version:3.4
build:e9kem
```

From this, how can I parse just the `build:e9kem` out? The data varies every time, so once it recognizes the word `build`, would like to parse just that line.

Comment: Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your question.
Great questions tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community. At minimum, you should provide a [mcve] of what you have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/^build:(.*)$/m
```

should do the trick. The `m` flag will cause the `^` and `$` anchors to match at the beginning and end of the line.

If you call this as

```
string.match(regexp)
```

The matching part (after the `build:`, the part matching `.*`, which is the string `e9kem`) will be in the second element of the resulting array.

```js
const regexp = /^build:(.*)$/m;

const stringPar = `SchoolDistrictCode:291238-9
location_version:3.4
build:e9kem`;

console.log(stringPar.match(regexp)[1]);
```

Of course, `match` returns `null` if there are no matches, so you may want to check that:

```
var matches = stringPar.match(regexp);
if (matches) console.log(matches[1]);
else console.log("No match.");
```

Or, another common idiom is

```
console.log((stringPar.match(regexp) || [])[1]);
```

which will log `undefined` if there is not match.

Comment: Sorry but how do I apply it to the string paragraph? Say the string is called `var stringPar`.

Comment: "Paragraph" is a linguistic term. I guess you mean "multi-line string". Use `stringPar.match(regexp)`.

Comment: What is `regexp` and where does `/^build:(.*)$/m` go?

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked beautifully, but before I accept the answer and upvote, could you explain why and what is `[1]` and what each character is doing in `/^build:(.*)$/m;`? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Check out the documentation for [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#Return_value) to understand how it returns an array, where the first element is the entire match, and the second and succeeding elements are the individual "captured" groups. Therefore, the second element (addressed by `[1]`) is what matches `(.*)`, the parentheses denoting a capture group.

Comment: Check out the [documentation for regexp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to understand things like `^`, `.`, `*`, and `$`, or paste the regexp into a regexp tester such as regex101.com, and it will give you an English-like description of what it does.

Comment: Got it! Thank you for the breakdown. Really helped. But for certain multi-line string, it returns `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null` when I try to display the string such as `stringPar.match(regexp)[1]` but it console logs the string properly when console logged like `console.log(stringPar.match(regexp)[1])`. What could possibly be the issue? Thank you in advance!